# Aptana Studio can't resolve the import but works

Tags: aptana, pydev, suds

I have just installed [suds](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Fedorahosted-retirement) and given a try for it in [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/). While, it seems not to resolve `from suds.client import Client` by underscoring it in red, the following code still works. So, I have decided to install Eclipse-Plugin for Pydev by running the same code. This time Eclipse Plugin can resolve Client as expectedly. 
Why can't Aptana Studio resolve this class, unlike Eclipse Plugin? Is this kind of a bug, or have I screwed something while installing suds package?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed and Auto Configured python interpreter from Window->Preferences->PyDev and it works now.

I was to delete such a simple question, but leave it here for the similar situation for others.